# I can log into my localhost, but can't log in to website online

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I tried everything I can. I keep getting query errors such as: `mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established`. But here's the thing, on my website, I can view everything I uploaded to my database using `mysqli` not `mysql`. So I'm thinking for the register/log in system I need to change that. Here is the code that works for local host:

**connection.php:**

```
<?php
$connect_error = "Sorry, there are some connection issues! Check back shortly!";
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lr") or die($connect_error);
mysqli_select_db("lr");
?>
```

**int.php:**

```
    <?php
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);


require("connect.php");
require("general.php");
require("users.php");



$errors = array();
?>
```

**users.php:**

```
    <?php

function change_password($user_id, $password){
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $password = md5($password);

    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '$password' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
}

function register_user($register_data){
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}

function user_count(){
    return mysql_result (mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1"), 0);
}

function user_data($user_id){
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_get_args > 1){
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

        return $data;
    }
}


function logged_in(){
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true :  false;
}

function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
  return (mysql_result( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='$username' "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
  return (mysql_result( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` ='$email' "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
return (mysql_result( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='$username' AND `active` = 1 "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username ($username) {
        $username = sanitize ($username);
        return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password){
        $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

        $username = sanitize($username);
        $password = md5($password);

        return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'"), 0)==1) ? $user_id : false;
}

?>
```

Now notice how everything up there is in `mysql` not `mysqli`.

**general.php:**

```
    <?php


function array_sanitize(&$item){
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}

function sanitize($data){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

function output_errors($errors){
    $output = array();
    foreach($errors as $error){
        $output[] =  $error; 
    }
    return implode('', $output);
}
?>
```

**login.php:**

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    include("connect.php");
    include("int.php");

if(empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) ===  true){
        $errors[] = '<div class="error-notice">
                     <div class="oaerror warning">
                     <strong>Oops!</strong>
                     You need to enter a username and a passsword!
                     </div></div>';
    }   else if(user_exists($username) === false){
        $errors[] = '<div class="error-notice">
                     <div class="oaerror info">
                     <strong>Hmm.</strong>
                     Username not found. Have you registered first?
                     </div></div>';
    }   else if(user_active($username) === false){
        $errors[] = '<div class="error-notice">
                     <div class="oaerror warning">
                     <strong>Oops!</strong>
                     Your account is not activated! Be sure to check your mail!
                     </div></div>';
    }   else{

        if (strlen($password) > 32){
            $errors[] ='<div class="error-notice">
                        <div class="oaerror warning">
                        <strong>Oops!</strong>
                        Your password is too long!
                        </div></div>';
        }

        $login = login($username, $password);
        if($login === false){
            $errors[] ='<div class="error-notice">
                        <div class="oaerror danger">
                        <strong>Uh oh!</strong>
                        Your Username/Password is incorrect!
                        </div></div>';
        } else{
            // set the user sesssion
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            // redirect user to home
            header("Location: index.php");
            ob_end_flush();
            exit();
        }
    }
} else{
}
echo output_errors($errors);        

    if (logged_in() === true){
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }else{
    }

?>
```

So like I said before, I can view everything I uploaded to the site such as images. Here is the code for that, that actually works:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("hostgator.com", "", "password", "photos");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<a href='uploads/".$row['image']."' data-caption='".$row['text']."'> ";
                echo "<img  id='img_div' title='".$row['image']."' alt='".$row['image']."'  src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/>";
                //echo "<p id='img_div'>".$row['desc']."</p>";
                echo "</a>";
                echo'';
```

And notice in that one I am using mysqli_query not mysql_query and it works out. Is there anyway that I can log in to my website correctly just as I able to log into the localhost? Does this have something to do with mysql_querys? I am just not understanding my errors.

> **Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO
>   instead in /home3/user/public_html/general.php on line 9**
>
> **Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home3/user/public_html/general.php on line 9**
>
> **Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home3/user/public_html/general.php on line 9**
>
> **Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home3/user/public_html/users.php on line 48**

**If there's more info you need just ask.**

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: well it says "Access denied for user...". Are you sure your password/username are correct? Is the hostname correct? and what about the database name?

Comment: is your MYSql server started on you web host? Is it on the same server as the web site?

Comment: @LSA yes. Because It works when I upload my images on the website and I can see them.

Comment: I think so. @jmarkmurphy. They are on phpmyAdmin if that's what you mean.

Comment: @aynber can you give me an example, please?

Comment: @AshleyHoward Simply add an i to the end of all your mysql_* commands. So instead of `mysql_connect` it will say `mysqli_connect`

Comment: That was a bad example as you're already connecting with MySQLi, for your queries, use `mysqli_`.

Comment: All examples can be found in the links provided. There are a ton of tutorials out there on how to use mysqli, and how to convert mysql queries to mysqli queries.

Comment: @AshleyHoward just because you can use PHPMyAdmin doesn't mean the HTTP server and the Database server are on the same physical box. If you can access the database using PHPMyAdmin, it does, however, mean that the database server is operational.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I'll check and see if this works!

Comment: you do a `mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lr")` are you sure, that there is no password? And for the code that you say it works you do a `mysqli_connect("hostgator.com", "", "password", "photos")`, are you still sure that your credentials are correct?

Comment: Yes, I can prove it to you with my site: www.quotin.co. I just need to apply the same logic inorder for the login system to work.

Comment: How can you not understand these errors? `Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` You haven't entered your password.. All Mysql_ functions are no longer being supported therefore you need to either update your code or downgrade your PHP version on the server. If the server is hosted by someone you'll have to find somewhere else who allows mysql_ or update your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue due to php version on your server .
php  removed mysql from  PHP 7.0.0

You have two option

1. Downgrade your php version
2. update your code with mydqli or PDO

Comment: What do you mean by updating the code? Like switch `mysql_` to PDO? If so, can you give me an example of that?